# Can't get values from form in a jQuery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm having a ton of trouble with this form I created on a WordPress site. It uses Gravity Forms, and submissions are handled through AJAX.

The form exists on a modal (using custombox jQuery plugin) which is triggered when you click the "Contact" menu item.

Basically, jQuery events don't work on the form. If you hit submit without filling in the proper fields, the form fails to trigger a validation error message. If the form IS filled out correctly, the entry is saved but no confirmation message is sent.

I've tried handling the validation myself (pasting code below), but I can't get the values of the inputs unless you refresh or hit submit a 2nd time. Upon initial submit, it only returns the initial values, not the new ones.

I have the script loading in the head, and inside a document ready function. I'm completely out of ideas and would really appreciate any help!

```
$('body').on('submit', '.custombox-content form#gform_1', function(){
    console.log('submit');
    var inquiry_type = $('.inquiry select').attr('value');
    console.log(inquiry_type);
    //validateForm();
});
```

Here, I'm trying to get the value of a select input. When the form is submitted, 'submit' is logged along with the initial select field value. It doesn't log the real selected value until I hit submit a 2nd time.

Comment: Are there multiple `.inquiry select` elements on the page at all? Might want to be more specific when referring to that value on submit e.g. `$(this).find('.inquiry select').attr('value')` so that you can be sure it's value is the correct one.

Comment: @sbeliv01 that worked! I've been banging my head against a wall with this for hours. I guess the modal plugin creates a copy of the form, so there was 2. Thanks for your help!!